# Finding nearest value in T-SQL from array of elements

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Working on point redemption app. I have  a query returning point ranges as below:

```
Point
-----
50    
100    
150
```

I have a local variable having accumulated points. Say If I have 65 points then I will be able to redeem 50 points only. If I  have 110 then I will be able to redeem 100 and so on.

I tried to use `select case` & `between` but it wasn't coming correctly.

Kindly help.

Comment: do you want the nearest value or the nearest value which is smaller than your variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 p.*
FROM Points p
WHERE p.Point <= @PointVar -- or < @PointVar
ORDER BY p.Point DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim, i know it was silly... Your solution was quick and easy

Answer (score 1):

Try to use subquery sa below

```
select points
from tab
where points = (select max(points)
                from tab
                where pointst <=@locaL_variable )
```

Comment: I think it should be `pointst < @locaL_variable` less than or equal to like `pointst <= @locaL_variable`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT top 1 * FROM [myTable] 
ORDER BY ABS( points - @input )
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9052/3)**

Comment: This will give wrong answer if you put greater than 125. It give 150 instead of 100.

Comment: @SelvaTS:- As far as I have understood the problem thats what the OP is looking for. `Finding nearest value in T-SQL` A value greater than 125 is nearest to 150 and not to 100 :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi: i guess that OP has just used the wrong term _nearest_, so your answer might still be helpful for future readers. But as it seems he was just loooking for a way to find the nearest point which is smaller than a given point (_"Working on point redemption app"_).

Comment: @TimSchmelter:- Got that, I just went with the wordings. My bad :(